# Regex match after semicolon and separated comma

Tags: javascript, regex, perl, pcre, regex-group

I have a string like

```
Menu: apple, orange-juice, bananas
```

I want to use REGEX to match only **apple** **orange-juice** **bananas**
I have tried to search Google and regex101.com for help but still no any idea.

I would appreciate any help! Thank you

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having? Please show us your code. (Hint: I'm not sure that a regex is the best tool here.)

Comment: @DaveCross I tried regex pattern like: ([^,\s][^\,]*[^,\s]*) but I have no idea to exclude "Menu:"

Comment: @NguyenDuyTanTo: Use `[a-zA-Z-]+` regex which will match the words you want to. What do you exactly want to do? If you don't want commas in your string, you can just remove all commas from your string.

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy Hello, could you please edit your answer in regex101.com link. Like my wish comment below, thank you very much :((

Comment: @NguyenDuyTanTo like [this](https://regex101.com/r/N0AfW7/2) ?

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy No, like https://regex101.com/r/N0AfW7/1 but instead of it bold the **apple** **orange-juice** **bananas**

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy because the input is a variable have the same format, not a static string

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy Your answer, it bold "Menu:" and "," and "," but the my desire answer inverse with you, it must "apple" and "orange-juice" and "bananas"

Comment: Like this: https://regex101.com/r/TOTWq0/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following in javascript :

```js
var string = "Menu: apple, orange-juice, bananas";
console.log(string.replace(/Menu: |\,/g, ""))
```

Regex101 : https://regex101.com/r/N0AfW7/1

Comment: Thank you very much but... I write code in bash, and grep it. So I just need the regex pattern. Could you please write your pattern in regex101.com and show it for me. Thank you very much!

Comment: @NguyenDuyTanTo updated my answer. Note that you can't replace in regex, you need JS for that. Regex is only used to find out patterns in strings.

Comment: Yes, I know, the story that I write in bash, "grep" will help me output, but I stucked with the regex pattern to find out words in string. Thank you very much for your help but... I'm a newbie in this field can you reverse your answer in regex, exactly that it bold the **apple** **orange-juice** **bananas**